# How to set read only field dynamically in Blade(Laravel)

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want set read only field dynamically :

*In Controller:*

$is_read =true;

*In Blade form:*

`{!!Form::text('name',$company_name,array('id'=>'rc_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name','readonly'=>'$is_read'))!!}`

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readonly attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an input field is read-only.

A read-only input field cannot be modified (however, a user can tab to it, highlight it, and copy the text from it).

The readOnly property sets or returns whether a text field is read-only, or not.
So  readOnly="true" or readOnly="false" is not effected its working.

I've fixed it with following:

```
{!!Form::text('name',$company_name,array('id'=>'rc_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name',$is_read ? 'readonly':''))!!}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
{!!Form::text('name',$company_name,array('id'=>'rc_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name', $is_read ? 'readonly' : ''))!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your input field in the blade

`{{$is_read ? 'readonly':''}}`

it could be something like below

`<input type="text" class="input form-control" id="rc_name" name="rc_name" value="{{$company_name}}" {{$is_read ? 'readonly':''}} >`